# setting up function to be called later during click event

Tags: jquery, function, animation

I have an animation function that will happen everytime a bunch of buttons are clicked, they'll all each have something specific happen, but the animation will happen everytime.  Right now I have it set up so it's part of the click, so I've redefined each time, how do I set it up once and then for each button just say run that function when clicked?

right now it's set up as this:

```
$("#animation1").click(function() {
$("#clinic_850_CONTAINER").animate({
    height: box_TOTAL_ht + 20
}, 300);

$("#staff_850_CONTAINER").animate({
    marginTop: staff_850_CONTAINER_ht * -1
}, 300);

$("#profile_850_HEADER").delay(160).animate({
    top: 10
}, 270);
$("#profile_850_BIO").delay(330).animate({
    top: profile_850_HEADER_ht + 20
}, 400);
$("#profile_850_EDU").delay(450).animate({
    top: profile_850_HEADER_ht + profile_850_BIO_ht + 20
}, 400);
$("#profile_850_CONTACT").delay(570).animate({
    top: profile_850_HEADER_ht + profile_850_BIO_ht + profile_850_EDU_ht + 20
}, 400);

});
```

setting it up like so runs on page load, how do you prevent it from it from running until the click happens but keep them seperate

```
function profile_850_close_animation() {
$("#staff_850_CONTAINER").animate({
    marginTop: 0
}, 300);

$("#clinic_850_CONTAINER").animate({
    height: staff_850_CONTAINER_ht
}, 300);

$("#profile_850_HEADER").animate({
    top: box_TOTAL_ht + 20
}, 300);
$("#profile_850_BIO").animate({
    top: box_TOTAL_ht + 50
}, 450);
$("#profile_850_EDU").animate({
    top: box_TOTAL_ht + 60
}, 450);
$("#profile_850_CONTACT").animate({
    top: box_TOTAL_ht + 70
}, 450);  
}

$("#profile_850_CLOSE").click(profile_850_open_animation());
```

Comment: define a class for all the buttons and bind click handler to that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these would work:

```
$("#animation1, #animation2, #animation3").click(function() {
    // existing code
});
```

or

```
function animate() {
    //existing code
}
$("#animation1").click(animate);
```

Comment: i like the second idea, but when I do that the animation just runs onload

Comment: If it is running onload, it is likely because you typed `.click(animate())` instead of `.click(animate)`. You need to pass a function reference (not call the function).

Answer (score 0):

Setup classes for these to be applied to.  I would need to see the html structure to better refine your click handler and animations, but you can specify relative to the animation click or perhaps have a check for the id to determine what other elements to animate.

Answer (score -1):

```
function animation() {
// Animation code goes here
}

$("#animation1").click(animation);
```

Also, you can use jquery selectors to select all the buttons and assign their onclick event at once. For example if all of the animation buttons were of class button

```
$(".animation").click(animation);
```

Comment: There is also a special selector to select all buttons :button http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DSelectors%26redirect%3Dno

Comment: so when I set it up that way the animation just runs onload

Comment: You don't pass `animation()`, you just pass the function name (no parens) like this `$("#animation1").click(animation);`

Comment: hmm, so I added it to the top what I tried, how would I alter that?

Comment: oops, okay I just reread what you wrote, yes that works, thanks!